# Rails: friendly_id slug relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, relationship, friendly-id

I want to create a slug for my model which depends on a column of a related model. Is that possible?

Here is what I've thought:

```
# Example::User class
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id user.username, use: :slugged
belongs_to :user, class_name: "::User"
```

I get the following error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass

---

**Edit:** How records are created.

I have a `User` and `Example::User` model.
When running:

```
User.create(email: "demo@example.com", name: "demo", password: "12345678").encrypted_password
```

a `Example::User` record gets automatically created:

```
# User class
before_action :create_example_user

has_one :example_user, class_name: "Example::User"

def create_example_user
    Example::User.create(user_id: self.id)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
extend FriendlyID
friendly_id user_username, use: :slugged
belongs_to :user

def user_username
  user.username
end
```

Edit:

Because your example user is trying to reference the user prior to the user being saved, it is causing the error.

Changing

```
def create_example_user
    Example::User.create(user_id: self.id)
end
```

to

```
def create_example_user
    self.build_example_user
end
```

may fix the problem

Comment: Can you post the relevant code that is creating the user and this association?

Comment: in your `before_action` callback, try changing `Example::User.create(user_id: self.id)` to `self.example_user.create`

Comment: Hmm.. I get `NoMethodError: undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass`. Dunno why the relation is not working...

Comment: My bad, the example user doesn't exist yet. Try `self.build_example_user`

Comment: that gives me: `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`

Comment: is that maybe creating new `User` and `Example::User` records?